# read / write Files in project folder

Tags: java, maven, file-io, io, project-folder

Hi I was wondering how to access files in the project folder in java/maven, i have thought about using src/main/resources, but i have been told it is a bad idea to write to files in this directory, and should only be used in configuration for the project, So i have created a new non source folder but i was wondering if there is a way to access this file in java without giving an absolute path, as i need to use it in different env. any help or other suitable suggestions would be great here thanks. i will be writing to the files at runtime.

EDIT:

i am using this to acces the file:

```
private static final String ACTUAL_VALUES ="verification/actualCounterValues.csv";
```

where `verification` is a folder i have created in my project

Comment: What do you mean with "different environments"? Just Java SE? JEE? It would of course be possible to use a Java Content Repository, but this will likely be too much for a small application.

Comment: If you need to use code in different environment then you need to access the files using "relative paths". What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I mean Linux/windows for different env, @Hirak i ment absolute paths not relative see edit

Comment: You can use private static final String ACTUAL_VALUES ="verification"+File.separator+"actualCounterValues.csv";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you, your goal is to access a file from within your app, without hardcoding a relative path because you're going to run it on different environments.

The first thing you may have to solve is to decouple the file-reference from your app - because if you move your app it must adapt to the new environment.
You may solve that by putting an absolute file-reference into the system-environment (which is accessible through the [`System.getenv()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)) method). Another way could be to deliver the file-path as [command-line-argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

After that you have to specify when which running instance of your app will access the file. If your application runs separated in the maven and a production environment - everything is fine with using relative paths in the maven-project. The production-app will then generate and use its own file in its environment.

If they must share the file, you have to provide physical access from both environments to that file-path, after that you may access that file with separate absolute paths (delivered through cli-args or system-properties) or with "hard coded" relative paths, which access a file-link (which point to that absolute file).

But i must discourage you from using any hardcoded configuration-specific variables for ongoing maintenance reasons.

And if these two application-instances will access both one single file, you should also be aware of possible concurrency difficulties (especially in the filesystem - see that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713550/concurrent-file-write-in-java-on-windows)).