# Synchronizing on an Integer results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

This question is based on  [Synchronizing on an Integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value).

The solution there seems excellent only there is small problem it does not address the concern how to delete values from `ConcurrentHashMap`.

So to address that I did below program

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Example {

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public void doSomething(int i) {
        synchronized (getLockForId(i)) {
            concurrentHashMap.remove(i);
        }
    }

    public Integer getLockForId(int id) {
        concurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(id, id); // I want to replace these two
                                                // operation with single one
                                                // since it seems the cause of
                                                // NPE
        return concurrentHashMap.get(id);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Example example = new Example();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (true) {
                    example.doSomething(++i);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (true) {
                    example.doSomething(++i);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Problem is that it always results in `NullPointerException`. My first analysis was because I am deleting the value it gets assigned to null so it is causing `NullPointerException`. So I did below

```
    Object obj = new Object();
    synchronized (obj) {
        obj = null;
    }
```

But above does not result in `NullPointerException`. So My question is why it is throwing `NullPointerException` in above case?

Even if I do

```
public Integer getLockForId(int id) {
   return concurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(id, id); 
}
```

It still results in `NullPointerException` because it only returns value when there is one else return `null`

Comment: This question is based on Synchronizing on an Integer *object* not value.

Comment: Why do you need to remove values from map when you're done?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Eventually there has to be a point where those need to be removed right? The problem it that point needs to be synchronized. I see no other solution for it then.

Comment: @Aubin I can not change text of Previous question :)

Comment: I don't see reasons why you need to remove these keys, actually. Only if you may have about 2^32 different ids during your application lifetime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well yes, that *would* throw a `NullPointerException`. Consider this pattern:

```
 Thread 1                     Thread 2

 putIfAbsent (puts)
 get (returns non-null)
 acquire monitor
                              putIfAbsent (doesn't put)
 remove (removes value)
                              get (returns null)
                              acquire monitor (bang!)
```

It's not that the "value get assigned to null" - it's that `Map.get` returns null if there's no entry for the given key.

It's hard to know what to recommend, as your code really doesn't do anything *useful*. If you can say what you're trying to achieve in your *real* code, we can give you better suggestions, potentially.

EDIT: As noted by Nikita, just returning the value of `putIfAbsent` doesn't work, as that returns the *previous* value, or `null` if it was absent - whereas you want the *new* value for the entry.

I suspect you'll have to synchronize access to the map, basically, to make your `getLockId` method atomic with respect to the `remove` operation.

Comment: Returning result of `putIfAbsent` still results in `NPE`

Comment: @AmitD: With the code you've given? It really shouldn't... will test it when I've got access to a properly multi-core machine (as my netbook doesn't show the problem even with the first code.)

Comment: @JonSkeet `ConncurrentMap` returns `null` if key is absent in map. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29

Answer (score 2):

You can try to make all accesses to `concurrentHashMap` synchronous. So when you get value from map you synchronize on `concurrentHashMap` and when you remove it. Something like this:

```
public void doSomething(int i) {
    synchronized (getLockForId(i)) {
        // do stuff
        synchronized (concurrentHashMap) {
            concurrentHashMap.remove(i);
        }
    }
}


public Integer getLockForId(int id) {
    synchronized (concurrentHashMap) {
        concurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(id, id);
        return concurrentHashMap.get(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then there remains no point of having this [solution in question] solution :) Because you no more have multiple locks you are only synchronizing on one lock.

Comment: I think you need both lock. Because when you manipulate with getting/releasing id from map - you use lock on this map. When you some stuff with current id - you have lock on this id. So there are no 2 concurrent threads doing stuff on same id while map is not locked and other threads can work on other ids.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using google's LoadingCache instead.  It uses weak references, so garbage collection is left to the JVM; you don't have to delete references you no longer need.  And it handles the concurrency issues involved with creating a new entry.  The code for a value synchronizer would look like this:

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ValueSynchronizer<T> {
  private final LoadingCache<T, Lock> valueLocks;

  public ValueSynchronizer() {
    valueLocks = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
      new CacheLoader<T, Lock>() {
        public Lock load(final T id) {
          return new ReentrantLock();
        }
      });
  }

  public void sync(final T onValue, final Runnable toDo)
  {
    final Lock lock = valueLocks.getUnchecked(onValue);
    lock.lock();

    try {
      toDo.run();
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Actually syncing on a value would look like this:

```
private final ValueSynchronizer<Long> retrySynchronizer 
    = new ValueSynchronizer<>();

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(final EventThatCanBeSentMultipleTimes event)
{
  retrySynchronizer.sync(event.getEventId(), () ->
  {
    //...Your code here.
  });
}
```

(licensed under Apache 2.0 license: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)