# What is the best way to increase number of locks?

Tags: java, concurrency, locks

This question is based on [Synchronizing on an Integer results in NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890214/synchronizing-on-an-integer-results-in-nullpointerexception) and originated from this question [Synchronizing on an Integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value)

I wanted to know what is the best way to increase number of locks in Java. Other than which is implemented in `ConcurrentHashMap` i.e. Based on Fixed array and by calculating hash of key to refer index of array?

Below is what is expected.
 If `doMoreThing()` for one object is in process then I should not do `doAnotherThing()` for the same object if it called from different thread.

```
public void doSomething(int i) {
    doAnotherThing(i);// some checks here based on it it will call to
                        // doMoreThing
    doMoreThing(i);
}
```

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. ConcurrentHashMap does not 'increase the number of locks in Java'. From 'below is example I'm which if I am doing' your post is unintelligible.

Comment: Can you please refer to original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value.

Comment: Can *you* please confine yourself to your original question, instead of double-posting it.

Comment: @EJP Because this is entirely different context. context was limited in the previous question as in I referred some implementation which does not provide solution. So Now the question is there a different way. I don't know how you think these two things are same. I would love to hear from you if you know solution :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616141/java-threads-locking-on-a-specific-object

Answer (score 4):

Every `Object` in Java has an associated lock.  If you want a new lock, you can create a new `Object`.  The referenced question doesn't make it clear why you're trying to increase the number of locks, or what you mean by that.  Maybe you can provide more details.

**Update following changed question**

I think I see what you're aiming at: effectively, you want a `synchronized` block on the `int` that `doSomething` is getting passed.  There are two relatively simple ways to do what you're after:

a) Is it *really* important that several threads be able to call `doSomething` simultaneously with *different* `int`s?  If not, you could just place both calls within a `synchronized(this)`

b) `int`s are not `Object`s.  If you change `doSomething` to take an `Integer` and also change whatever's calling `doSomething` (and whatever's calling that, and so forth) to also use `Integer`s, you can synchronize on the `Integer`.  It's important here to make sure that every caller will be using the same `Integer` object - it's possible to have multiple `Integer`s that have the same `int` value, but synchronizing on different `Integer`s won't provide the protection you're looking for.

Comment: Updated the question. I hope now its more clear.

Comment: Yeah locking on a value that can change (like an `Integer`) is a really bad pattern although I understand what you are trying to get at.