# Java: How to create synchronized block and that subclasses use

Tags: java, inheritance, synchronization

```
abstract class A {
  protected abstract int isRunning();

  public void concreteMethod() {
    synchroinzed(isRunning()) {
       //do stuff
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  int running_ = 0;

  public int isRunning() {
     return running_;
  }
}
```

The problem I get: int is not a valid type's argument for the synchronized statement. How do I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to prevent simultaneous execution of your block and isRunning ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: @SLaks the class is more complex then the above but I just hit this roadblock which is "int is not a valid type's argument for the synchronized statement."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent simultaneous execution of your block and the method `isRunning()`, you can't do it exactly as you want because `synchronization` can't be inherited (only an implementation can justify `synchronization`).

Here's the nearest you can do :

```
class A {
  protected Object lock = new Object();
  protected abstract int isRunning();
  public void concreteMethod() {
    synchronized(lock) {
       //do stuff
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  int running_ = 0;    
  public int isRunning() {
    synchronized(lock) {
     return running_;
    }
  }
}
```

If you can afford to lock the entire `concreteMethod()` and not just a block, you have the simple solution to add the `synchronized` keyword to the `concreteMethod` and `isRunning()`:

```
class A {
  protected abstract int isRunning();
  public synchronized void concreteMethod() {
       //do stuff
  }
}

class B extends A {
  int running_ = 0;    
  public synchronized int isRunning() {
     return running_;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a lock on primitive value (`int` in your case since `isRunning()` returns an `int`).

Try to replace `int` by `Integer` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) say

```
Another way to create synchronized code is with synchronized statements. Unlike synchronized methods, synchronized statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock
```

Meaning, for synchronization you would first need an object to lock on. Since `int` is not an object you get an error. An `Integer` object would not give this error but just using an `Integer` instead of `int` would not guarantee correctness.

Here is a very good tutorial on java concurrency

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html

Comment: ok lets forget its being synchronized on a integer. then what if the synchronizing was on a boolean

Comment: Any primitive types would not work as a synchronization construct. A Boolean would work and not boolean.

Comment: The answer to "why can't we use `Integer` instead?" is described here very well http://stackoverflow.com/a/659939/1276636

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing two concepts.
Synchronized block always asks for reference as its parameter time but you are passing int (primitive data type ) as its argument. You can try using 'this' keyword (in place of isRunning() method) as synchronized block parameter.
Also you need to declare  class A as abstract.
Also there is a spelling mistake in your code.
You can also consider @dystroy 's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
class A
{
  protected abstract int isRunning();

  public synchronized void concreteMethod()
  {
       //do stuff
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  int running_ = 0;

  public synchronized int isRunning()
  {
   return running_;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** `sychronized` block is accompanied by an `Object` whose **lock is needed to be obtained to access that block by the thread of execution.**

**-** `int` is a `primitive` type and **not** an object.

**-** Creating an sychronized block along with an Object of the Super-Class is well accessible by its Sub-Classes.

**Eg:**

```
public void concreteMethod()
  {
    synchroinzed(A.class) // or synchroinzed(A.class)
    {
       //do stuff
    }
  }
```