# Thread synchronization based upon an id

Tags: java, thread-safety

I need a way to allow only one thread to modify data related to a service ticket. More than one thread may be attempting to modify the ticket data at the same time.

Below is a simplified version of my approach. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe with java.util.concurrent packages?

```
public class SomeClass1
{
    static final HashMap<Integer, Object> ticketLockMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();


    public void process(int ticketNumber)
    {
        synchronized (getTicketLock(ticketNumber))
        {
            // only one thread may modify ticket data here

            // ... ticket modifications here...
        }
    }


    protected static Object getTicketLock(int ticketNumber)
    {
        Object ticketLock;

        // allow only one thread to use map
        synchronized (ticketLockMap)
        {
            ticketLock = ticketLockMap.get(ticketNumber);

            if (ticketLock == null)
            {
                // first time ticket is locked
                ticketLock = new Object();
                ticketLockMap.put(ticketNumber, ticketLock);
            }
        }

        return ticketLock;
    }
}
```

Additionally, if I don't want the HashMap filling up with unused locks, I would need a more complex approach like the following:

```
public class SomeClass2
{
    static final HashMap<Integer, Lock> ticketLockMap = new HashMap<Integer, Lock>();


    public void process(int ticketNumber)
    {
        synchronized (getTicketLock(ticketNumber))
        {
            // only one thread may modify ticket data here

            // ... ticket modifications here...

            // after all modifications, release lock
            releaseTicketLock(ticketNumber);
        }
    }


    protected static Lock getTicketLock(int ticketNumber)
    {
        Lock ticketLock;

        // allow only one thread to use map
        synchronized (ticketLockMap)
        {
            ticketLock = ticketLockMap.get(ticketNumber);

            if (ticketLock == null)
            {
                // first time ticket is locked
                ticketLock = new Lock();
                ticketLockMap.put(ticketNumber, ticketLock);
            }
        }

        return ticketLock;
    }


    protected static void releaseTicketLock(int ticketNumber)
    {
        // allow only one thread to use map
        synchronized (ticketLockMap)
        {
            Lock ticketLock = ticketLockMap.get(ticketNumber);

            if (ticketLock != null && --ticketLock.inUseCount == 0)
            {
                // lock no longer in use
                ticketLockMap.remove(ticketLock);
            }
        }
    }
}


class Lock
{
    // constructor/getters/setters omitted for brevity
    int inUseCount = 1;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use something like `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap` for the ticket locks and avoid the `synchronized` bit which is poorly performing. `putIfAbsent()` should be exactly what you need.

Comment: @Jeff check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value

Comment: @manub ConcurrentHashMap can not handle this, because we need lock on both `getTicketLock `  and `releaseTicketLock `  method.  BTW, I think this approach is good enough, with no condition problem, no memory leak, after I see lots of bad solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the [`Lock` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). The second case could be solved by a [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), which counts the number of times it has been locked.

Locks have a `.lock()` method which waits for the lock to acquire and an `.unlock` method which should be called like

> ```
>  Lock l = ...;
>  l.lock();
>  try {
>      // access the resource protected by this lock
>  } finally {
>      l.unlock();
>  }
> ```

This could then be combined with a `HashMap<Integer, Lock>`. You could omit the `synchronized` calls and cut down on lines of code.

Comment: How do you make sure that the locks get removed from the map when they are not going to be used any longer in a thread-safe way so that you make sure that the map doesn't grow out of control?

Comment: @user3289695 what about using something like Guava cache with key expiry? That's just an assumption.

Comment: @user3289695 : how about checking the ReentrantLock.getHoldCount and deleting from the map if 0 ?