# Managing the product count in the database

Tags: java, database, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Excuse me if this question may seem naive but I have come across a scenario where I need to manage the product count in the database of an e-commerce store.

There is a Product class with an integer variable `productCount` which signifies the number of available products in the database which is visible to users of the site. Now this class is accessed by several threads or can say several users of the e-commerce site. Everyone is adding or removing the product to his cart.

The ORM framework being used is hibernate

Sample code

```
@Entity
@Table
class Product{
   @Column
   private int productCount;

   public void addProductToCart(){
     // decrements the product count by 1 & updates the database
   }

   public void removeTheProductFromTheCart(){
    // increments the product count by 1 & updates the database
   }
```

As it is clear from the code that I need to keep a concurrency check on the product count in the database to prevent lost updates.

Also if several users are trying to add only single left product in the database. Which user's cart the product should be added to?

I did a little research on this

Possible ways I found were

1. Creating a singleton class for Product. That would ensure that just one instance of product is available throughout the application.
2. Synchronize the `addProductToCart` &  `removeTheProductFromTheCart` methods. 
   which would allow only one thread to update the product count & update the db at a time.
3. Use database concurrency control apply some db transaction isolation level, optimistic/pessimistic locking for the `productCount`. I am using mysql the default isolation level is `REPEATABLE_READ`.

What would be the best approach to deal with this?

Comment: Have you thought of making the product count a view, i.e select count * from producttable where productid == x. That way you dont need to keep the product count in memory and deal with concurrency. You just check the DB everytime you need to display the count. And let the db handling the locking

Comment: Where are the shopping carts persisted?  Knowing that might help.

Comment: Everything is persisted into mysql db

Comment: are you really going to let a user park an item in his shopping cart where it may likely expire without having been bought, and deny others the chance to buy it?

Comment: no Nathan it's just a use case not the final code. I understand product count should be decremented only when the user checks out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first two possibilities you are considering, those work only if you are restricted to deploying only a single instance of the application. You can't have singletons managed across multiple application instances, you can't have synchronization across multiple JVMs. So if you go with one of these your deployment options will be constrained, the only way to deploy multiple instances of the application is if you do something like pin the sessions to a specific instance, which is bad for load-balancing. So these both seem undesirable.

The approach of getting the product counts from the database has the advantage that it remains valid as your application scales up across multiple instances without messing up load-balancing.

You may think, this will only be one instance on one server so I can get by with this. But at the time you're building an application it may not be entirely clear how the application will be deployed (I've been in situations where we didn't know what the plan was until the application was set up in a preprod environment), or at a later date there might be a reason to change how an application is deployed; if your application has more-than-expected load then it may be beneficial to set up a second box.

One thing that is not apparent to me is how vital it is that the product count is actually correct. In different business domains (airline tickets, shipping) it's common to overbook, and it might be more trouble than it's worth to keep a 100% accurate count, especially if it's at an early point in the process such as adding an item to the shopping cart (compared to the point where the customer actually commits to making a purchase). At the time the customer buys something it may make more sense to make sure you reserve those items with a database transaction (or not, cf. overbooking again).

It seems common in web applications to expect a low conversion rate from items in the cart to items actually purchased. Keep in mind what level of accuracy for your counts is appropriate for your business domain.

Comment: In stackoverflow questions are forced to be to the point and technical, else the questions are closed as broad topic by moderators. where as the answers are too broad for conclusion. Hypocrisy.

Answer (score 8):

**3. Use database concurrency control**

Why?

- 1 & 2 are OK if your e-commerce app is absolutely the only way to modify the product count.  That's a big if.  In the course of doing business and maintaining inventory the store may need other ways to update the product count and the e-commerce app may not be the ideal solution.  A database, on the other hand, is generally easier to hook into different applications that aid the inventory process of your store.
- Database products usually have a lot of fail-safe mechanisms so that if something goes wrong you can trace what transactions succeeded, which didn't, and you can roll back to a specific point in time.  A java program floating in memory doesn't have this out of the box, you would have to develop that yourself if you did 1 or 2.  Spring and Hibernate and other things like that are certainly better than nothing but compare what they offer and what a database offers in terms of recovering from some electronic disaster.

Answer (score 2):

IMO a conventional layered approach would help here - not sure how radical a change this would be as don't know the size/maturity of the application but will go ahead and describe it anyway and you can choose which bits are workable.

**The theory...**

```
Services   a.k.a. "business logic", "business rules", "domain logic" etc.
 ^
DAOs       a.k.a. "Data Access Objects", "Data Access Layer", "repository" etc.
 ^
Entities   a.k.a. "model" - the ORM representation of the database structure
 ^
Database
```

It's useful for the entities to be separate from the DAO layer so they are just simple units of storage that you can populate, compare etc. without including methods that act on them. So these are just a class representation of *what* is in the database and ideally shouldn't be polluted with code that defines *how* they will be used.

The DAO layer provides the basic CRUD operations that allow these entities to be persisted, retrieved, merged and removed without needing to know the context in which this is done. This is one place where singletons can be useful to prevent multiple instances being created again and again - but use of a singleton doesn't imply thread safety. Personally I'd recommend using Spring to do this (Spring beans are singletons by default) but guess it could be done manually if preferred.

And the services layer is where "domain logic" is implemented, i.e. the specific combinations of operations needed by your application to perform particular functions. Thread safety issues can be tackled here and there will be times when it is needed and times when it isn't.

**In practice...**

Following this approach you might end up with something like this (lots omitted for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class ShoppingCart {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shoppingCart")
    private Set<Product> products;
}

public class ShoppingCartDao { /* persist, merge, remove, findById etc. */ }

@Transactional
public class ProductService() {
    private ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> locks = 
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public void addProductToCart(final int productId, final int userId) {
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = shoppingCartDao.findByUserId(userId);                               
        Product product = productDao.findById(productId);
        synchronized(getCacheSyncObject(productId)) {
            if (product.shoppingCart == null) {
                product.setShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
            } else {
                throw new CustomException("Product already reserved.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeProductFromCart(final int productId, final int userId) {
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = shoppingCartDao.findByUserId(userId);
        Product product = productDao.findById(productId);
        if (product.getShoppingCart() != shoppingCart) {
            throw new CustomException("Product not in specified user's cart.");
        } else {
            product.setShoppingCart(null);
        }
    }

    /** @See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915#659939 */
    private Object getCacheSyncObject(final Integer id) {
      locks.putIfAbsent(id, id);
      return locks.get(id);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Are you sure productDao.findById will return always the same (==) object?

Comment: Good spot. No I wasn't 100% sure about that but did briefly think about it! Decided to keep the code compact since there are some complexities here and it's only supposed to be an example - in reality, one way would be to use the entity's primary key instead as the identifier instead of the entity object itself. If it's a simple auto-increment integer then a map or set of these could be maintained as per the advice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value#659939).

Comment: it's only the same object within the current entitymanager. this won't work. using synchronization for this is a bad idea.

Comment: It will work if you use a unique identifier for the entity instead - as [mentioned above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465008/managing-the-product-count-in-the-database/35529274?noredirect=1#comment-58807906), this can be done easily enough but adds extra complexity to the code fragment, which I was attempting to keep as simple as possible - see the "lots omitted for brevity" comment.

Comment: @NathanHughes would you please elaborate a little more on the same object within the current entity manager. I believe the product object is fetched from the db won't it be same every time?

Comment: @underdog: as far as the persistent entities are concerned, if the entity isn't present in the 1st level cache then a new object gets constructed and populated from the database. from that point on in the session the entity manager keeps that copy cached and returns it when needed. but for different sessions the entities are different objects. hence the workaround for comparing PK values in the comments above where Steve includes a link.

Comment: @underdog: Since there seemed to be enough desire to see it I've now updated the answer to include the code for synchronizing on entity ID (primary key) instead of the entity object instance.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do it is use database locks, as it designed for this work. And if you are using hibernate it's pretty simple with LockRequest:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()
Transaction transaction;
boolean productTaken = false;

try {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Product product = session.get(Product.class, id);
    if (product == null)
        throw ...

    Session.LockRequest lockRequest = session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.UPGRADE);
    lockRequest.lock(product);
    productTaken = product.take();
    if (productTaken) {
        session.update(product);
        transaction.commit();
    }
} finally {
    if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive())
        transaction.rollback();
    session.close();
}
```

Here we are fetching product from database for updating which prevents any concurrent updates.

Answer (score 1):

Let's evaluate three options.

> 1.Creating a singleton class for Product. That would ensure that just one instance of product is available throughout the application.

Single instance for product is fine. But if you are offering a Product like Mobile with quantity 20, still you have to `increment` product count (static variable ) on `addProductToCart` and `decrement` product count on `removeTheProductFromTheCart`. Still you have to synchronize the access to this mutable count Or update database and read product count.

> 2.Synchronize the addProductToCart &  removeTheProductFromTheCart methods. which would allow only one thread to update the product count & update the db at a time.

This is one solution but I prefer third one : Remove synchronization in application and provide data consistency at database layer.

> 3.Use database concurrency control apply some db transaction isolation level, optimistic/pessimistic locking for the productCount. I am using mysql the default isolation level is REPEATABLE_READ.

Defer consistency to database instead of application. But you have to use `READ COMMITTED` for isolation level instead of `REPEATABLE_READ`

Have a look at this [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html)

> **READ COMMITTED**

`A somewhat Oracle-like isolation level with respect to consistent (nonlocking) reads`: Each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads its own fresh snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood carts are also persisted in db? And as final result bought products too.

product:

```
[{id:1, count:100}]
```

cart:

```
[{user_id:1, product_id:1}, {user_id:2, product_id:1}]
```

bought :

```
[{user_id:3, product_id:1}]
```

Then you can get count for the product

```
select count as total from product where id = 1
select count(*) as in_cart from cart where product_id = 1
select count(*) as total_bought from bought where product_id = 1
```

now you can show final count by

```
int count = total - (in_cart + total_bought);
```

This way you guarantee that there will not overriden or bypassed increments/decrements. Finally beside code check for count you can also add a trigger in DB level which checks for the total count and if the product can be inserted in carts or bought tabel.

If your product count is changing daily, I mean yesterday you had 100 product and sold 20, today 50 products has arrived, thus you should have 150 - 20 sold count which is 130. In order to have a good reports you can make product count daily. like

```
 [
  {id:1, count:100, newly_arrived: 0, date: 23/02/2016}, 
  {id:1, count:80, newly_arrived: 50, date: 24/02/2016}
 ]
```

then your queries will change like

```
select count+newly_arrived as total from product where id = 1 and date = today
select count(*) as in_cart from cart where product_id = 1 and date = today
select count(*) as total_bought from bought where product_id = 1 and date = today
```

for this you have to only insert new product data at midnight 00:00:00 and when your new products arrive in the morning you can update newly_arrived without intervening any insert or delete operations on carts or bought tables. and you can have detailed reports easily without making sophisticated report queries :))

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a relational database for this (and not a key value store e.g.).  I would highly recommend to do this as close to the storage as possible to avoid locks and conflicts and get the highest performance as possible.

On the other hand it sounds like a typical scenario where multiple nodes are working on one database which also creates problems with latency due to Hibernate session handling.

At the end you need statements like

```
UPDATE product SET productCount = productCount + 1 WHERE id = ?
```

To be executed in a transaction maybe using a simple JDBC statement or by a JPA repository method with @Query annotation.

To make Hibernate aware of the changes you can use `Session.refresh()` on the product after such an operation.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do that work in ecommerce web app, using **Messaging Queue** . You can use **RabbitMQ** ,

1. Create a queue on rabbitMQ and keep all requests here that reduce product count
2. because of queue all request will be processed one by one so there wont be any conflicts to reduce product.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't so much a technical question as a process question.  Personally, I would not reduce inventory until someone had actually purchased the product.  Adding an item to a shopping cart is an indicator that they may purchase it.  Not that they have.

Why not reduce the inventory count only when the payment has successfully processed?  Wrap the entire thing in a database transaction.  If 10 people add the same item to their cart and there is only 1 left, then the first to pay wins.  9 folks will be upset they didn't pay faster.

The airlines reference is different.  They do issue temp holds, but it is way more complicated than managing inventory.  That and they are working with a fluid pool of seats that they monkey with as the inventory becomes scarce.

Comment: How does this answer the question asked?