# Synchronizing based on contents of Map

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I want to synchronize a block of code, but do not want to simply lock on the implementing class (this).

The block of code in question is part of a method which takes in an id.

I want to disallow a new thread from entering the block if the id passed into the method is contained within a list in the class... if it not in the list, the entity is free to operate on, and thus the thread will be allowed into the block...

Is there a straight forward way to do this?

Comment: This might be the answer you're looking for:http://stackoverflow.com/a/17776425/1499922

Comment: What do you mean with “disallow”? `synchronized` will never disallow, it might only block until available, so what is your desired behavior?

Comment: why would you need `synchronization` in the first place? a simple check will not do, like `!if(list.contains(id)) return`?

Comment: Guava has a nice [Striped](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) class for this sort of thing, so you don't need to roll your own.

Comment: @Eugene I especially like how the duplicate is itself a duplicate of a question that's closed as "not a real question". I'm wondering whether to reopen this.

Comment: @Eugene Yea, I had this same requirement a while ago, and I was trying to find an existing implementation in the JDK, but Striped is a very good shrink-wrapped solution to this.

Comment: For the record, this was closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value

Answer (score 5):

There is no explicit class for this in the JDK, but as described in the (previous) [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value), you can use `ConcurrentHashMap` to implement this kind of behaviour.

Guava provides the [Striped](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) class that gives you a good solution with plenty of configuration, such as lazily creating locks and weak locks, as well as configuring the amount of stripes (locks) to be used.

Comment: as promised, a one plus.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not in it for the points though, I just wanted to include this so people won't think they need to roll their own solutions for things like this. I couldn't add this as an answer to the duplicate because...it's closed.

Comment: I know, up-vote was exactly for that. So that I would not make a fool of my-self showing a dumb solution.

Comment: Striped locking is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Well, the linked Q&A is from 2009, when you indeed had to built such a feature *atop* `ConcurrentHashMap`, but with Java 8, the `ConcurrentHashMap` *is*  such a feature, i.e. `concurrentMap.compute(key, (k,v) -> { action; return v; }` performs `action` under a key specific lock. For a lot of cases, this is already sufficient.

Comment: @Holger True enough. However I also appreciate the clarity that you're working with locks, instead of a *collection* that involves locking although the end result is the same.