# Issue in JAVA synchronization with static Object as lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, race-condition

Please refer the below code where 200 threads are trying to increment the `counter` variable simultaneously.

The program tries to do the same 100 times. It prints the value of variable in case the incremented value doesn't reach to 200 - meaning some threads interfered with each other.

To avoid interference, I used `synchronized` keyword. It works well if I use `synchronized` on static lock object (commented line), but if I use `synchronized` on `counter` variable, I still see many times the value doesn't get incremented to 200.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Class {
    public static Integer counter = new Integer(0);
    
    //public static Object lock = new Object();

    static void increment() {
        synchronized (counter) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            counter = 0;
            List<Thread> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                Thread t = new Thread(() -> increment());
                list.add(t);
                t.start();
            }
            for (Thread t : list) {
                t.join();
            }
            if (counter < 200){
                System.out.println(counter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: `counter++` amounts to `counter = Integer.valueOf(counter.intValue()+1);`, which reassigns the `counter` variable, so synchronizing on its old (or new) value is instantly futile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Synchronizing on an Integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) is immutable, so `counter++` resolves to and assigns a different instance for the incremented value.

So `synchronized (counter) {}` synchronizes on a different monitor when different instances of `Integer` become visible to the current thread.

The solution is to use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which features a [`getAndIncrement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement()) method which increments the value as if a lock was held.

```
private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

static void increment() {
    counter.getAndIncrement();
}

// ...
counter.setPlain(0);
// ...
if (counter.getPlain() < 200) {
// ...
```

[`setPlain()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#setPlain(int))/[`getPlain()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getPlain()) can be used instead of [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#set(int))/[`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#get()), since `Thread#start()` and `Thread#join()` make sure what happened before is visible and what happens next can see what happened before, respectively.

---

Note that a method reference can be used here:

```
Thread t = new Thread(Class::increment);
```

Note that [`Integer(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) is deprecated:

```
Integer counter = 0;
```

Comment: I'm on board with most of this answer, but `setPlain` still seems unsafe to me, since multiple threads are read-update-write-ing the same value. If you put `setPlain` inside a `synchronized` block, sure...that would work I suppose.

Comment: @Max: when `setPlain` is used before any of the accessing threads are started, then it's safe, since there's no risk of race conditions.

Answer (score -3):

Integer is not a right choice as a lock object. For that purpose AtomicInteger has been developed.
So the following code should work as expected.

```
public class Class {
public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

static void increment() {
    synchronized (counter) {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        counter.set(0);
        List<Thread> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(Class::increment);
            list.add(t);
            t.start();
        }
        for (Thread t : list) {
            t.join();
        }
        if (counter.get() < 200) {
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Also I would recommend to research AtomicInteger type in details to get a real understanding how it works under the hood and why Integer can not be used in a case like yours.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html
[Practical uses for AtomicInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818699/practical-uses-for-atomicinteger)

Comment: 1) Thanks but can you explain why Integer is not a right choice as a lock object? End of day, it is also an object so should be okay to use as mutex..
2) I think, if I use AtomicVariable and something like `incrementAndGet` then I don't even need `synchronized`. It will break only in case increment is done like `counter.set(counter.get()+1)`

Comment: Does this answer to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659915/synchronizing-on-an-integer-value ?

Comment: Yes, AtomicInteger is thread safe, in that particular scenario synchronization is unnecessary.

Answer (score -5):

public static **volatile** Integer counter = new Integer(0);

Use volatile to avoid visibility issues among threads. This should fix the problem.

Comment: The issue is with locking, I don't think `volatile` will solve it. Anyways tried and didn't work.

Comment: It will not help for sure, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749746/what-is-the-difference-between-atomic-volatile-synchronized)